# Generating array of array of divisors in python

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, optimization, sieve

I wish to get divisors of number n as a list stored in a master list at nth position. For example the sieve of length 11, I want sieve[6] == [2,3,6] (ignoring 1). My code below does not work and surprises me in an unpleasant way:

```
sieve = [[]]*11

sieve[1] = [1]

for i in range(2,11):

    for j in range(i,11,i):

        sieve[j].append(i)

        print ("appended", i ," at sieve",j)
        # This check-print statement shows that it works fine until sieve is printed. 
print (sieve)

sieve[6] turns out to be : [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Can that be explained please?

Answer (score 4):

Consider this example:

```
>>> a = [[]] * 5
>>> a
[[], [], [], [], []]
>>> a[0].append(1)
>>> a
[[1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
```

When you declare `sieve` as a product of lists, each of the individual lists is the same object and changes made to one are reflected across all. So you need to fix that.

```
sieve = [[] for _ in xrange(11)]
```

You can of course just simplify the whole process by using list comprehension.

```
sieve = [[], [1], [2]] + [[j for j in xrange(2, i) if i%j == 0] for i in xrange(3, 11)]  # 0, 1, and 2 are special cases
```

Answer (score 2):

You have copies of the *same* array created by the term `[[]] * 11`.  So if you modify one of the inner array, *all* are modified in the same way.

You can create a list of independent arrays by sth like `[ [] for i in range(11) ]` for example.